# Deciphering values of symbol table - PE file format

Tags: c++, c, winapi, portable-executable

According to MSDN documentation:

> The symbol table is an array of records, each 18 bytes long. Each
> record is either a standard or auxiliary symbol-table record. A
> standard record defines a symbol or name and has the following format.

And from the COFF file header, one can obtain two variables: PointerToSymbolTable, which is the offset from the start of the mapped file to the symbol table, and NumberOfSymbols, which describes the number of symbols in the table.

My goal is to parse this symbol table, in order to find specific functions in my code, and their addresses. Therefore, I wrote the following code as a test, to find the "Type" value of the first record of the symbol table:

```
    //This part is correct, no errors.
        LPBYTE lpFile = (LPBYTE)MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, dwFileSize);
        PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpFile;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS coffHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)dosHeader + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

//Part in which I am not getting the expected values
    LPBYTE symBuff = (LPBYTE) malloc(18);
    LPBYTE startPoint = lpFile + coffHeader->FileHeader.PointerToSymbolTable;
    memcpy(symBuff, startPoint, 18);
    DWORD symType = (*symBuff << 14) >> 17;
    printf("symType: %02x", symType);
    if (symType >> 1 == 0x20) {
        printf("Is a function");
    }
    if (symType >> 1 == 0x00) {
        printf("Is not a function");
    }
```

The objective here is to move the mapped file pointer to the location of the symbol table, and obtain the Type value of its first record, which is located on the 14th position of the table and is defined as such:

> A number that represents type. Microsoft tools set this field to 0x20
> (function) or 0x0 (not a function). For more information, see Type
> Representation.

When printed, however, I get the value 0x05, which I did not expect, because my code isolates the most significant byte.

> The most significant byte specifies whether the symbol is a pointer
> to, function returning, or array of the base type that is specified in
> the LSB. Microsoft tools use this field only to indicate whether the
> symbol is a function, so that the only two resulting values are 0x0
> and 0x20 for the Type field. However, other tools can use this field
> to communicate more information.

Comment: Image files don't contain symbol table, object files do. And object files don't contain the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`, they start with an `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER` .

Comment: _`an array of records, each 18 bytes long`...  Caution:  if `LPBYTE symBuff = (LPBYTE) malloc(18);` this is creating a string ensure that you include room for null termination. (1 extra byte.)  The fact that elements of array records are list as 18 bytes long suggest you are probably okay, but typically if length is determined using `strlen()` for example,  as opposed to sizeof (buffer), it will not include null termination.

Comment: I thought LPBYTE, being a "pointer to a byte", would not create a string. That's funny.

Comment: @jtxkopt, if PE files contain no symbol table, why is there a valid PointerToSymbolTable value, and NumberOfSymbols? In this case, it apparently isn't jibberish - there were 1171 supposed symbols in my supposed table, when printed out.

Comment: The type of `*symBuff` is `unsigned char`. Shifting an 8-bit value 14 places to the left, and then 17 digits to the right doesn't appear to be a meaningful operation. Whatever your bitshifts are supposed to do, they probably won't.

Comment: @functionhunter This info is not used for PE **image** files. Look at the msdn doc, carefully. - Your question is not clear for me. What are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @functionhunter For parsing the symbol table of an object file, use the `IMAGE_SYMBOL` structure in the `winnt.h` file.

Comment: *"my code isolates the most significant byte"* - It doesn't. It uses **bit**shifts, that are both wrong and needless. If you want to read a `WORD` value at **offset** 14, just do that: `WORD type = *(WORD*)(startPoint + 14)`. It's still wildly unclear what ultimate problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I was looking for some way of doing that, and thought bitshifts were the right tool for the job. That's a good solution thank you.

Comment: @functionhunter Are you trying to parse an exe file or object file?

Comment: It can be either a .exe or a .obj, I am looking for the fastest way to calculate a functions size in bytes, along with its address and final delimiting position. My idea to do this was to compile to .obj or .exe and parse it. Interpret symbol table -> find addr or function -> find delimitation -> get size.

Comment: Just have the compiler emit a PDB and use the [DIA SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-interface-access/debug-interface-access-sdk) to gather this information. Though it seems that answers to the questions you ask are unlikely to help you make forward progress towards a solution to your actual problem. You will need to take a step back and start to understand the *problem*.